# How to remove borders around links in IE?

Tags: html, css

I have a navigation bar which consists of a `<img>` elements within their respective `<a>` elements. However, for some reason in IE its making a dark black border around the images. Its not doing the same in other browsers, I can't seem to figure this out... This is the html that I'm using.

```
<li>
   <a href="#">
      <span id="nav1">
         <img src="tt_1.png" />
      </span>
   </a>
</li>
```

I have about 5 links all written like that and I've used CSS to style it into a nav bar. On other browsers it comes out like this [image: good bar]

but on IE it comes out like this [image: Bad bar :(]

I've never encountered a problem like this before and what I've reserached to try and fix it so far haven't worked. Is there a way to take out these borders using CSS?

Answer (score 126, accepted):

**TL;DR**

Remove borders from all links and images:

```
a, img {
    border:none;
    outline:none; /* this breaks accessibility */
}
```

---

**Full version**

If you only want to remove borders from images that are links, you should do the following:

```
a img {
    border:none;
    outline:none; /* this breaks accessibility */
}
```

The only difference is that there is no comma between `a` and `img` meaning only images inside `a`-tags will have this rule applied

**Pro tip: Use a css reset**

Browser inconsistencies like this one are numerous, so web developers often use a "css reset" i.e. https://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/ or http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/. This will (among other nifty things) reset things like borders, margins, etc. on a number of elements so they render more consistently across browsers.

#### Note on accessibility

The dotted outline, that is often judged as disturbing by developers, has a very important function for keyboard users.

You should *never* remove it. If you do, you need to find another visual indicator of where focus is, by adding a [`:focus` style](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:focus)

Comment: I have added an _outline:none_ style to remove the dotted border around active links in IE.

Comment: Jonathan Newmuis's answer is more correct

Comment: I have updated this answer to avoid the unintended consequences that have led some people to prefer Jonathan Newmuis's answer.

Comment: `outline: none` is awful for accessibility and is completely unneeded to fix the issue.

Answer (score 75):

I believe IE puts borders around images that are links.  So you should be able to remove this by saying:

```
a img {
    border: 0;
}
```

Comment: I think this is the best answer because it achieves the specific intent, the accepted answer might have unintended consequences.

Answer (score 12):

add `style="border: none;"` to whatever creates the border or create a css with this attribute.

Comment: This was downvoted. I still find that this is useful when applying the style to only one element. This is also a good practice when sending HTML emails, in which case you can't create a CSS rule.

Comment: One shall never apply style within a html-document.

Comment: @IliasBennani actually, there is no restriction on this in any standard. Furthermore, you cannot style any email without inline CSS. As well, it is useful for interactive elements with custom-styled/relative behavior/animation.