# HTML ahref on Internet Explorer

Tags: html

So this is my HTML code

```
<header>
<a href="index.htm"><img src="images/logo.png" alt="Affandi" /></a>
</header>
```

I dont have any problem with it, when I open it on Chrome, Opera, and Firefox.
But then, when I try to open it on Internet Explorer!

This is what happen

[image]

I dont know why suddenly my logo has a gray border if I open it on Internet Explorer.

Please tell me if you have a solution, I'm totally new on this html coding.
*And sorry for my bad English writing.

Thank you all! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding:

```
header a {
    border:none;
}
```

Or simply:

```
a {
    border:none
}
```

If you dont want the border on any of your links in IE.  IE is known for adding borders around links, and many reset.css files will handle this for you out of the box.

Also see:

[How to remove borders around links in IE?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7910209/how-to-remove-borders-around-links-in-ie)

Answer (score 3):

Just add a attribute "border" to tag IMG.

```
<img src="images/logo.png" alt="Affandi" border="0" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to delete the border.

Try this in html :

```
<header>
<a href="index.htm"><img src="images/logo.png" border="0" alt="Affandi" /></a>
</header>
```

Or in css:

```
<header>
<a href="index.htm"><img src="images/logo.png" style="border:none" alt="Affandi" /></a>
</header>
```

Comment: Np Aurelia! Thx for the edit Aerox, was a mistake :)

Answer (score 0):

try making img border equal to zero in your css