# Internet explorer displaying image links with colored border

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, image

I have the following CSS code for links:

```
a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #248AC9;
}

a:hover {
    color: #8DCFF7;
}
```

The problem is that in Internet Explorer, images have a strange border with the same color as 'color'. How can I fix this, and draw images correctly. The HTML code is simple: 
`<a href="calculator-operators.htm"><img src="img/link.png" /></a>`

[image: Screenshot:]
So, how can I fix this problem?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How switch off image border in IE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2958688/how-switch-off-image-border-in-ie)

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Just specify no border for the images:

```
a > img{
    border: 0;
}
```

Comment: This fixed the problem... thanks :) And I like this solution better, because it doesn't interfere with other (non-link) img styles.

Comment: Note that you don't need to specify the unit type when using zero values. i.e.  0; will suffice.

Comment: how, for something so common, is this Q&A not voted higher?!

Answer (score 6):

Use

```
img {
   border: 0;
}
```

I would consider using a [reset](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/) stylesheet, or a [normalising](http://necolas.github.com/normalize.css/) stylesheet to provide consistency in styling across all browsers. This fix is part of those stylesheets.

Answer (score 3):

Its an old post i see, but i thought, why not. There is an other solution by using `border:none;`:

```
a img {
   border:none; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

just set the border from all image to 0 px

```
   img { border: 0px }
```

Answer (score -2):

Try

```
a { 
    text-decoration: none; 
    border:0;
    color: #248AC9; 
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work. And painting with white is not a solution... background is a very light gray, not white.