# hide visited link hilighting css

Tags: css, image, hyperlink, visited

I've been making a site and on the header I have some .png images being used as buttons, my problem is when I open the site in ie9 the visited images have a purple outline. My question is how do I disable visited link highlighting on images or make it transparent so it doesnt come up.

Comment: `a:visited { border: none; }`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Internet explorer displaying image links with colored border](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9249244/internet-explorer-displaying-image-links-with-colored-border)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I don't want to show a link visited state I just set it the same as a the regular link state like so:

```
a, a:visited {
    // my styles
}
```

And then another rule for hover and focus:

```
a:hover, a:focus {
    // my styles
}
```

And another for active if required:

```
a:active {
    // my styles
}
```

If you have images that are getting a border on them as a link or visited link and you don't want this you should add the following to your css:

```
img {
    border: 0;
}
```

Comment: I tried pasting that into the CSS document but it didn't work. If you could add a bit more detail that would be great, I'm just starting CSS and am a bit confused.

Comment: @user2072017 - I've added a llittle bit about image links with borders to my answer. I'd recommend looking at using a rest file like this one as a good starting point for dealing with lots of simple things like this: http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/

Comment: Thanks so much! It was the [img{border: 0;}] that fixed it.