# Removing blue outline/border from image anchor IE

Tags: html, internet-explorer, outline

To start off, I don't even know what this is.
I tried `text-decoration: none`, `border: none`, `outline: 0`, and nothing seems to work?
My CSS file is working all right, so it's not that?

Here's a picture:
http://i38.tinypic.com/rbgv3k.jpg

```
<div id="links">
  <span id="user"><a id="link" href="register.php"><img src="images/user.png"/></a></span>
  <span id="follow"><a id="link" href="https://twitter.com/itsybitsycom"><img src="images/follow.png"/></a></span>
  <span id="about"><a id="link" href="about.html"><img src="images/about.png"/></a></span>
  <span id="stats"><a id="link" href="profile.php"><img src="images/stats.png"/></a></span>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#link {
  text-decoration:none;
  border:0;
  outline:none;
}
```

Comment: Can we have a chance of having a look at your HTML? BTW try adding `img{border:0}` to your CSS

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How switch off image border in IE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2958688/how-switch-off-image-border-in-ie)

Answer (score 32, accepted):

try adding following to your CSS

```
img{ border:0 }
```

Answer (score 15):

IE adds a border around images if they’re the child of an anchor. You can remove this by setting the border to none:

```
a img {
      border: none;
}
```

Answer (score 7):

```
a{
    outline: none !important;
 }
```

Worked for me.

Comment: This is the better answer in my opinion, as it will work with all anchor tags (not just images with anchors around them).

Comment: No. Some people don't want the blanket approach to everything. Some pages have both links and image links. How do you control this on the image links alone?

Comment: This didn't work for me in IE 11, had to go with border: 0 on the img

Answer (score 3):

You need to add the CSS to the image, not to the link. Instead of `#link`, you need to use `#link img` as the selector.

Then `border:none;` should work for you.

```
#link img {
    border: none;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
#link img a
 {
 border:0;
 outline:none;
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do it with this CSS:

```
border-style: none;
```

Comment: No, that only works on the <IMG> tag, not the <a> tag. The <a> tag is what's placing the "blue border" out there. CSS on the "a" is the only way I know how to avoid it